# Unique Select Query into Table Sqlite3

Tags: sql, join, sqlite

I have the following database structure

```
Table 1
EventID  |  Person1  |  Person2  | Person3  |  ...  | PersonN

Table 2
Person  |  Height  |  Weight
```

Now I would like a query that for a given `EventID` (which is unique) returns the persons involved along with their `Height` and `Weight`.

I was thinking of creating some sort of temporary table along the lines of

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t AS
SELECT Person1, Person2, Person3, ..., PersonN FROM Table1 WHERE EVENTID = ?
```

and then joining the temporary table `t` with `table2` but of course this doesn't work as what I want is the transpose of `t`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Consider normalizing `Table1` to `EventID | PersonIndex (if even needed) | Person`

Comment: Agreed, not sure if this would be a new question then, but how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Instead of inserting one row of `EventID, P1, P2, P3, ...` (which is hard to query and limits the number of persons tied to an event), you would insert one `EventID, Person` row for every person. The query then becomes trivial: `SELECT Table2.* FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Person = Table2.Person WHERE Table1.EventID = ?`

Comment: Right, I meant is there a good way of normalising my table as it currently is, using SQL (not at the insert stage)?

Comment: `INSERT INTO NewTable SELECT EventID, Person1 FROM OldTable WHERE Person1 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL SELECT EventID, Person2 FROM OldTable WHERE Person2 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL ...` Not pretty but you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t2.person, t2.height, t2.weight
from table2 t2
join
(select person1 as person,event_id as person from table1 
 union select person2,event_id from table1..
 select personN,event_id from table1) t3
on t3.person = t2.person
where t3.event_id = ?
```

This is the more generic approach i can think of. But as the comments mentions you should consider changing the table structure.

Comment: I edited the question to highlight the need for a general solution

Comment: modified it but not sure if it is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

If you are given the event id, you can use `exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t2.person in (t1.person1, t1.person2, t1.person3) and
                    t1.eventid = $eventid
             );
```

Your data structure, however, is not very suitable for scaling purposes.  The problem data structure would have an `EventPersons` table, with one column for `EventId` and one column per `PersonId`.

Comment: I edited the question to highlight the need for a general solution

Comment: @rwolst . . . A table has a fixed number of columns, so just put all the columns in the `in` list.  Of course, your table borders on the ridiculous.  The right way to structure the data is using a junction table with one row per event and person.